# IPC API library in .NET

Tags: .net, dll, interface, ipc, publishing

I have desktop application A1.exe written in .NET C# and I would like to create something like A1API.dll, that could be used by other third party applications for interprocess two way communication with my application A1.exe.

I already have some prototype of A1API.dll that is based on IPC Remoting. In the dll there is Client.cs MarshalByRefObject class containing its own thread that keeps connection to instance of Server.cs MarshalByRefObject class by checking it every second. This construction allows to my A1.exe application to be restarted with automatic reconnection of all Clients which are also registered in Server for listening to A1.exe events. Also, if any client app is unexpectedly closed, server removes it from its collection of clients because it starts throwing errors even when method Client.Equals is called. This trouble I solved with ClientWrapper.cs class.

This all works quite qood!

Let say, that the library A1API.dll would be published on the internet as an API to my A1.exe application.

Now, I have got a problem. What if I will need to change A1API.dll in the future and extend for example some enumeration that is used in some public Server.cs method? Shall I use, in this case, string type instead?

In the scenario with enumeration, I will extend my A1.exe and A1API.dll, publish it, and then all clients depending on A1API.dll will break if only A1.exe will be reinstalled.

**What is the best solution for this whole thing?**

I will also appreciate any idea of improvement / change of my IPC solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends on how backwards compatible you want to be.

You may publish strongly named assembly (i.e. signed) and change assembly version every time API changes, so new assembly simply will not work with something expecting old one. Also, strongly named assembly can be put in the GAC so this is good idea anyway.

You may leave assembly not signed and/or not versioned, but instead add new Client class with new or modified methods. So you'll have Client100, Client101, Client203 classes.  Maybe you can play wiith inheritance, but I'd personally recommend against that.

First way allows you to mark new version/behavior change even when method signatures are not changed. Second way is the only way to add new functionality without breaking compatibility on source code level and allow compilation of old code against new version.

I'd say it is good to have both. Strongly named assembly in GAC, version increment on every change and new classes for new methods.